# Decomposition of a simple polygon by adding diagonals

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

The problem that I am facing is the efficient decomposition of a simple polygon (i.e. a polygon without holes) into smaller simple polygons by adding diagonals (that do not intersect themselves) in the initial polygon.
In other terms, here is the Java signature of the function that I'd like to implement efficiently (linear time or n*log(n) ) :

```
public static List<SimplePolygon> addDiagonals(SimplePolygon polygon, List<Edge> diagonals);
```

where polygon is that initial polygon that is represented by a double connected edge list and diagonals is a list of edges, where an edge simply consists of a start and ending node. The function must return a list of sub-polygons resulting by the addition of the diagonals in the polygon. Here is an image showing what I want:

[image]

The starting polygon is on the top left corner, and the 5 others are the sub polygons resulting by the the addition of the diagonals.
I have difficulties finding how to efficiently implement this decomposition, because it is easy to duplicate nodes incident to diagonals but if a lot of diagonals are going out from the same node I always have to check if the vertices adjacent to a node have been duplicated and if it is the case, then I add the diagonal to the duplicate (given that the original belongs to another sub-polygon), then I have to check again if this duplicated node has not also been duplicated (if there were already one diagonal adjacent to this node), etc..
Do you have an idea on how to do this decomposition efficiently ? Sorry if the explanations are not clear enough. 
Thanks!

Comment: The subdivision you show looks arbitrary to me. Can you clarify why the diagonals you've chosen are particularly good?  Usually people want to decompose into convex polygons, would you consider that a good solution? Also, can you give us your initial data for your example?

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey it's the decomposition into y-monotone pieces :) The initial data is only the (x,y) coordinates of the points of the polygon given in CCW order, starting from a random node.

Comment: @Jo8192 This seems to ask: given the diagonals, split the polygon. Wouldn't the algorithm that finds/computes the diagonals also be able to split the polygon? I would guess that it computes the diagonals while traversing the polygon...

Answer (score 0):

If the diagonals are indexed, you can use a vector helper, which counts the number of sp (sub polygons) generated for each diagonal. Each diagonal must generate 2 polygons...

1. Start this helper (number of sp for each diagonal) with size = number of diagonals and filled with zeroes.
2. Pick next diagonal: if the number of sp == 2, move to the next diagonal. If not:
3. increase the number of sp (in the helper vector), and generate the first polygon, which starts with the diagonal in question and visits the neighboring edges and diagonals until it reaches the first diagonal again, if in this process the sp generator visits another diagonal, increase the number of sp generated for that diagonal too.
4. If number of sp for the first diagonal == 1, run step 3 again.
5. If there are still diagonals unvisited, go back to step 2.

This way you guarantee to generate each sub polygon only once, with no duplicates.
Best.

Comment: The claim that each diagonal generates 2 polygons is not true.  Consider a  regular pentagon described by the following graph: ({1,2,3,4,5}, {(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,1)}).  If we add diagonals (1,3) and (1,4), we have three polygons.  If we add diagonal (2,5), we have six polygons.

Comment: You are right! I completely ignored the case when diagonals intercept... My bad.

Comment: @AymarFisherman This is ok for me given that the diagonals I want to add won't intersect :) I will try this later this week, I am busy right now. Thanks for your help, I will keep you informed :)

Comment: I guess if the diagonals did intercept you could do a pre-step to break the intercepting diagonals in multiple non-intercepting ones (from the interception point to each end of each diagonal OR next interception point). Nothing a little data conditioning wouldn't fix ;)